# Lots of INFO Log in Google App Server

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When running a test Servlet on Google App Engine, I get a lot of INFO log messages. Besides the messages, everything seems to work as expected. Is this something that I've to resolve, or it can be ignored?

I've [found an article](http://itstuff.jasonsmart.id.au/2009/05/gwt-plus-appengine-tutorial.html) describing the same problem, and I've followed the suggestion:

> Finally I went to the build configuration in Eclipse (Using the context menu for the project Build Path -> Configure Build Path... )
>   In the left menu I selected Google -> App Engine. Then on the right hand side I selected "Configure SDKs...". I changed nothing in the ensuing dialogue, because it all looked ok. App Engine appears in the SDK list and it is selected and the Location is ok. So I just clicked "OK".

One more JAR appeared in WEB-INF/lib, but despite that, after redeploy, the log messages were still there.

```
I 2011-11-27 05:19:15.193
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry resolveConstraints: 
Bundle "org.datanucleus.jpa" has an optional dependency to 
"org.datanucleus.enhancer" but it cannot be resolved

I 2011-11-27 05:19:15.195
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry resolveConstraints: 
Bundle "org.datanucleus" has an optional dependency to 
"org.eclipse.equinox.registry" but it cannot be resolved

I 2011-11-27 05:19:15.195
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry resolveConstraints: 
Bundle "org.datanucleus" has an optional dependency to 
"org.eclipse.core.runtime" but it cannot be resolved

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.268
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry resolveConstraints: 
Bundle "org.datanucleus.jpa" has an optional dependency to 
"org.datanucleus.enhancer" but it cannot be resolved

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.268
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry resolveConstraints: 
Bundle "org.datanucleus" has an optional dependency to 
"org.eclipse.equinox.registry" but it cannot be resolved

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.268
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry resolveConstraints: 
Bundle "org.datanucleus" has an optional dependency to 
"org.eclipse.core.runtime" but it cannot be resolved

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.503
org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property
datanucleus.rdbms.sql.allowAllSQLStatements unknown - will be ignored

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.506
org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property
datanucleus.rdbms.query.containsUsesExistsAlways unknown - will be ignored

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.506
org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property
datanucleus.rdbms.stringDefaultLength unknown - will be ignored

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.513
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl logConfiguration: 
================= Persistence Configuration ===============

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.517
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl logConfiguration: DataNucleus
Persistence Factory - Vendor: "DataNucleus"  Version: "1.1.5"

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.517
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl logConfiguration: DataNucleus 
Persistence Factory initialised for datastore URL="appengine" 
driver="" userName=""

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.518
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl logConfiguration:
===========================================================

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.771
org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property
datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns unknown - will be ignored

I 2011-11-27 05:19:17.772
org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property
datanucleus.query.cached unknown - will be ignored

I 2011-11-27 05:19:18.327
org.datanucleus.jpa.metadata.JPAAnnotationReader processClassAnnotations: 
Class "org.obliquid.goodeatin.Restaurant" has been specified with JPA 
annotations so using those.

I 2011-11-27 05:19:18.500
org.datanucleus.jpa.metadata.JPAAnnotationReader processClassAnnotations: 
Class "org.obliquid.goodeatin.Comment" has been specified with JPA 
annotations so using those.

I 2011-11-27 05:19:19.313
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.MetaDataValidator validate: Performing
appengine-specific metadata validation for org.obliquid.goodeatin.Restaurant

I 2011-11-27 05:19:19.315
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.MetaDataValidator validate: Finished 
performing appengine-specific metadata validation for
org.obliquid.goodeatin.Restaurant

I 2011-11-27 05:19:19.335
org.datanucleus.store.StoreDataManager registerStoreData: Managing 
Persistence of Class : org.obliquid.goodeatin.Comment 
[Table : <class name="Comment"
       identity-type="application"
       objectid-class="javax.jdo.identity.ObjectIdentity"
       persistence-modifier="persistence-capable"
       detachable="true"
>
<inheritance strategy="new-table">
</inheritance>
<property name="commentText"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true">
</property>
<property name="id"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       primary-key="true"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="false"
       value-strategy="identity">
</property>
<property name="restaurant"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="false"
       embedded="false">
</property>
</class>
, InheritanceStrategy : new-table]

I 2011-11-27 05:19:19.363
org.datanucleus.store.StoreDataManager registerStoreData: Managing
Persistence of Class : org.obliquid.goodeatin.Restaurant 
[Table : <class name="Restaurant"
       identity-type="application"
       objectid-class="javax.jdo.identity.ObjectIdentity"
       persistence-modifier="persistence-capable"
       detachable="true"
>
<inheritance strategy="new-table">
</inheritance>
<property name="address"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true">
</property>
<property name="comments"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="false"
       embedded="false"
       mapped-by="restaurant">
<collection element-type="org.obliquid.goodeatin.Comment" 
         embedded-element="false" dependent-element="true">
</collection>
<order>
</order>
</property>
<property name="dateAdded"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true">
</property>
<property name="description"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true">
</property>
<property name="id"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       primary-key="true"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="false"
       value-strategy="identity">
</property>
<property name="name"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true">
</property>
</class>
, InheritanceStrategy : new-table]

I 2011-11-27 05:19:19.375
org.datanucleus.store.StoreDataManager registerStoreData: Managing 
Persistence of Class : org.obliquid.goodeatin.Restaurant 
[Table : <class name="Restaurant"
       identity-type="application"
       objectid-class="javax.jdo.identity.ObjectIdentity"
       persistence-modifier="persistence-capable"
       detachable="true"
>
<inheritance strategy="new-table">
</inheritance>
<property name="address"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true">
</property>
<property name="comments"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="false"
       embedded="false"
       mapped-by="restaurant">
<collection element-type="org.obliquid.goodeatin.Comment" 
embedded-element="false" dependent-element="true">
</collection>
<order>
</order>
</property>
<property name="dateAdded"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true">
</property>
<property name="description"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true">
</property>
<property name="id"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       primary-key="true"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="false"
       value-strategy="identity">
</property>
<property name="name"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true">
</property>
</class>
, InheritanceStrategy : new-table]

I 2011-11-27 05:19:19.571
org.datanucleus.store.StoreDataManager registerStoreData: Managing 
Persistence of Class : org.obliquid.goodeatin.Comment 
[Table : <class name="Comment"
       identity-type="application"
       objectid-class="javax.jdo.identity.ObjectIdentity"
       persistence-modifier="persistence-capable"
       detachable="true"
>
<inheritance strategy="new-table">
</inheritance>
<property name="commentText"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true">
</property>
<property name="id"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       primary-key="true"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="false"
       value-strategy="identity">
</property>
<property name="restaurant"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="false"
       embedded="false">
</property>
</class>
, InheritanceStrategy : new-table]
```

Comment: Currently I experience the same issue in one GAE/J project. Did you already find a solution?

Comment: No, but I think you can safely ignore these log entries

Comment: You may be right, but I observe that when this happens, it costs a lot higher cpu usage.

Comment: However that was a test project with an older SDK, I will check if it happens again with the latest SDK

Comment: I suspected the same thing, so I created a new project from scratch using the latest SDK. Unfortunately, the result does not change. Anyway, I notice that my app previously generated a lot of request errors. Once I fixed this, both a-lot-of-INFO-in-log and high-pending_ms-in-request problems are gone. Not so sure it's related.

Answer (score 0):

isn't this configurable over the file:

```
/war/WEB-INF/logging.properties
```

I assume in your case it is set to show INFO logs. You should instead set it to

```
.level = WARNING
```

And later set individual classes to show INFO logs

Hope this helps!